# How to bump pref package to version 2.7.1 (needs Flutter 3.7.0) while I'm on the latest Flutter beta channel 3.7.0-1.5.pre?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, pubspec.yaml, flutter-pubspec

I'm on the Flutter beta channel, the latest `3.7.0-1.5.pre` version. I received a Dependabot PR about bumping the `pref` package's version to 2.7.1 (from 2.7.0), see https://github.com/TrackMyIndoorWorkout/TrackMyIndoorWorkout/pull/407. I was also eyeing that bump showed by `pub outdated` for a while now. If I specify `flutter: ">=3.7.0"` in my pubspec.yaml, then pub get gives this error:

```
The current Flutter SDK version is 3.7.0-1.5.pre.
Because track_my_indoor_exercise requires Flutter SDK version >=3.7.0, version solving failed.
pub get failed
```

But if I leave it at `flutter: ">=3.7.0-1.5.pre"` and I bump `pref` to 2.7.1 from 2.7.0 then I get:

```
The current Flutter SDK version is 3.7.0-1.5.pre.
Because track_my_indoor_exercise depends on pref >=2.7.1 which requires Flutter SDK version >=3.7.0, version solving failed.
pub get failed
```

It's also strange how the beta channel pins everything by SHA256, Dependabot doesn't do that. I switch from stable not so long ago due to package dependency problems, see https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/114199#issuecomment-1294263848 or https://github.com/TrackMyIndoorWorkout/TrackMyIndoorWorkout/issues/399.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this solved itself for now with Flutter 3.8.0-10.1.pre. Not sure about all of those SHA256 fingerprints, now looks like I see both the fingerprint and the version in some cases?